# (R) indentifies just one column in my data frame

Tags: r

I' m new to R. I have my data frame.

```
test<-read.csv("test.csv", header=TRUE)

sites   Jahr1   Jahr2   Difference1 Difference2
site1   0   2.208.630   2.208.630   
site2   10.531.793  9.439.612   1.092.181   10%
site3   1.942.681   1.283.180   659.501 34%
site4       456.168 456.168 
site5       450.697 450.697 
site6   6.022.843   5.644.573   378.270 6%
```

Now I want to look at my second coloumn...

```
names(test)
[1] "sites.Jahr1.Jahr2.Difference1.Difference2....."

test [,2]
Fehler in `[.data.frame`(test, , 2) : undefined columns selected
```

I think for advanced users, this is a very low level problem :)
Can you help me?

Comment: Please show the frist 3 lines of test.csv in your question. What you show indicates that your column separator is a space, which would mean you should try `read.table` with default separator.

Comment: sites Jahr1 Jahr2 Difference1 Difference2
site1 0 2208630 2208630 
site2 10531793 9439612 1092181 10%
site3 1942681 1283180 659501 34%
site4  456168 456168 
site5  450697 450697 
site6 6022843 5644573 378270 6%

Comment: i think r identifies just one coloumn instead of 5

Comment: Not in a comment. Edit your question.

Comment: Have you tried `read.table("test.csv", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)`?

Comment: yes i have. not working... :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is R can't detect the separation of your columns. Default separator is a space, you use periods.

Try `read.csv("test.csv",header=TRUE,sep=".")`

Comment: when i try thsi...

> test<-read.csv("test.csv",header=TRUE,sep=".")
Fehler in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  mehr Spalten als Spaltennamen
(i means that there are more colums than column names...)

Comment: That's probably because you use the `.` sign for not only the separation between columns but as your decimal sign as well. You should always use separate characters.

Comment: I don't think `.` is the column separator of the file. It looks like the whole file is read as one column and due to `check.names=TRUE` spaces are sanitized to periods in the column name.

Comment: ahh I understood. butt it´s still the same error :(

Comment: yeah i think roland answer will help me. let´s try